# Firebird - View parametrizada

Tags: firebird

Olá. Preciso criar uma View onde irei utilizar um parâmetro cujo valor será fornecido em tempo de execução (Delphi). Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo? Grato.

Comment: View de Banco de Dados ?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem o que você quer mas vou tratar como um projeto simples de delphi, mas basicamente para criar um componente em tempo de execução é simples.

```
pnlTitle            := TPanel.Create(frmPrincipal); // ou nil
pnlTitle.Parent     := frmPrincipal; //pode ser o formulário ou um outro componente onde o painel estará dentro;
pnlTitle.Top        := 0;
pnlTitle.Width      := 184;
pnlTitle.Left       := 0;
pnlTitle.Height     := 23;
```

é isso?